# Clarifai REST Api

Tags: clarifai

I am programming an application in .NET Core and after some browsing of [their repos](https://github.com/Clarifai) I don't think Clarifai has a .NET SDK. Is there a REST API I can use?

Answer (score 2):

Kunal from Clarifai here.

You can find the repo for the sdk over here, https://github.com/Clarifai/clarifai-csharp

We also have additional information on our documentation, https://clarifai.com/developer/guide/

As well as an example application to help you get started, https://github.com/Clarifai/quickstart-csharp-mvc-twilio